# Parse a version number given as a string into 4 distinct integers using in c

Tags: c, parsing

I have a version number returned as a string which looks something like "6.4.12.9", four numbers, each separated by a "."

What I would like to do is to parse the string into 4 distinct integers. Giving me

```
int1 = 6
int2 = 4
int3 = 12
int4 = 9
```

I'd normally use a regex for this but that option isn't available to me using C.

Comment: By the way, if this is in order to compare version numbers,  [`strverscmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strverscmp) will do that for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sscanf

```
int a,b,c,d;
const char *version = "1.6.3.1";
if(sscanf(version,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a,&b,&c,&d) != 4) {
  //error parsing
} else {
  //ok, use the integers a,b,c,d
}
```

Comment: And change `%d` to `%u` if you don't want to allow negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `strtoul`.

```
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char ver[] = "6.4.12.9";
    char *next = ver;
    int v[4], i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++, next++)
        v[i] = strtoul(next, &next, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As presented this is fragile - you'd want to check that `('.' == *next)` after each `strtoul` call, and also that `next` is changed by the `strtoul` call (to ensure each `.` is followed by a number).  Also note that `strtoul` allows whitespace before the digits, so you might want to check for that.  All in all `sscanf` is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a POSIX system, and limiting yourself to POSIX is okay, you can use the POSIX standard regular expression library by doing:

```
#include <regex.h>
```

then read the [relevant manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/regcomp/) for the API. [I would not recommend](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) a regexp-solution for this problem to begin with, but I wanted to point out for clarity that regular expressions are often available in C. Do note that this is not "standard C", so you can't use it everywhere, only on POSIX (i.e. "Unix-like") systems.

Comment: No they're not, it's not standard C, it's POSIX. I can't believe no one has pointed this out earlier.

Comment: @MichelRouzic D'oh. I suck. That's of course true, edited for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtoul()` to parse the string *and* get a pointer to the first non-numeric character. Another solution would be tokenizing the string using `strtok()` and then using `strtoul()` or `atoi()` to get an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could used [`strtok()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/) for this (followed by `strtol()`), just make sure you're aware of the semantics of [`strtok()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/), they're slightly unusual.

You could also use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Answer (score 0):

If none of them will exceed 255, `inet_pton` will parse it nicely for you. :-)